# Python Flask on Google App Engine - Routes Not Responding

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am creating a web app in python for Google App Engine.  The first route works fine, loading the home page:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Index.html contains a form for users to upload a file.  Now, this is a single page application, so the form is redirected through javascript to an invisible iframe to be submitted.  When python is done processing the file, the iframe then calls functions in the parent document to change what is shown.

Javascript function that redirects the form:

```
function redirect(elemid, tgt, sh1, sh2){
        document.getElementById(elemid).target = tgt;
        document.getElementById(elemid).submit();

        var callFunction;
        callFunction = show_and_hide(sh1, sh2);
    }
```

Flask route that processes the submitted form:

```
 @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
 def upload_file():
    #do something with file...    
    return response
```

Two things are strange:  (1) This all works fine on localhost.  The form redirects to the iframe and submits, the file is processed, and the response triggers the parent document's actions.  Its just gae that doesn't seem to work with it.  (2) When I remove everything from the upload_file() function, so that it just returns 'hello world', still nothing happens.  I have a second function that hides the upload div and shows a loading screen, which works, but nothing after that.

I have worked with app engine before on a php site, which required my app.yaml to provide instructions for every file on my app, but since there is only one page to load, my app.yaml file only contains the following:

```
runtime: python37

env_variables:
  CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: mybucket.appspot.com
```

Also, my requirements.txt is filled as follows:

```
Flask == 1.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy == 2.4.0
matplotlib == 3.1.1
NumPy == 1.17.2
SciPy == 1.3.1

google-cloud-storage==1.13.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
```

My suspicion is that this has something to do with app.yaml and the iframes, but I don't know what I would do to fix the issue (or if this even is the issue).

I would really appreciate any help!  Thank you in advanced!

UPDATE:
I added a form to index.html that employs the same action and method but does not redirect to the iframe as a test.  When I submit this form, I receive the message, "Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

UPDATE 2:
When I remove all of the code from the /upload route and change it with 'hello world', it does indeed return 'hello world'.

UPDATE 3:
When I inspect the iframe element, I can see that it has a message saying 'Request Entity Too Large, Your client issued a request that was too large'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was misinterpreting the problem.  GAE will not allow for file uploads > 32mb.  Instead, I will need to use the blobstore method.  Future humans can see details here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/